# How to test android app using test account with android in-app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have added my email id to the android in-app purchase testing account.

But When I am going to test the in-app purchase in to android device with this email id account, it is opening to ask to buy with the credit card details and purchase. So I am confused that how can I test the app in proper manner? Am I missing something to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately to test in-app billing you actually have to buy your item. Aside from [static responses](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) using fake item IDs there's no way to test the purchase with "fake money".

The good news is you can go into your merchant account and immediately issue yourself a refund, so you'll never actually be charged.